# Android SQLite : Lock + access from multiple threads

Tags: android, sqlite, concurrency, locking

I am trying to understand the possible ways to work with SQLite when there can be multiple threads work on DB.
Based on various responses in stackoverflow and other sites, it appears that there will be locking issue when same sqlitehelper instance is used from multiple threads. In a typical java application, I would expect instance to mean single object of type sqlite helper to be used by different threads of application.In such cases, the locks ,I guess, are a matter of correctly using the synchronized blocks. [Correct me here as I am not comfortable with this way of looking at sqliethelper instance here]

My concern is with sharing same data base : when one instantiate sqlite helper in different threads [ie each thread has its own object instance] but working on same Database [this I guess is more inline with having same db instance]. 
In such cases I'm getting frequent database lock errors. This occurs even when the threads are working on different tables of database.

In my application database can be updated by user interaction through application or by getting data through server [periodic synchronization]. And some time when synchronization process and user activity overlaps, I get the lock issues. As this pattern of data processing seems to be common in application synchronizing with server, would like to know how do lock issue due the concurrency is to be handled.

I would like to understand this since if this is bound to happen always then probably need to make only one handler over database and implement queue over that to avoid lock. But that will mean the complete application needs to be aware that the database may not get updated immediately and they need to implement listener to know when the data is actually updated in database.

thanks
pradeep

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know sqlite is intended for [single process usage](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5). No matter what you will always need to access the database from one thread at a time. You can do selects from multiple clients but can only write from one at a time. And other readers and writers will ahve to lock in the mean time.

As a side note - database access can hardly ever be considered instantaneous.

Comment: while its correct that DB access is hardly instantaneous but the underlying stuff is hidden. I will differ here instantaneous with synchronous call- well in typical programming, one gets the result of write operation synchronously. And if the result is a success, one can immediately do read for the corresponding data.  But my issue is here, if the locks are going to happen [even when two threads are working on different tables], and making me implement queuing behavior on database, then isn't it a significant difference from typical database programming one does on say even J2SE projects.

Comment: You are actually incorrect.  Multiple processes can access a SQLite database.  I have 2 android apps reading, inserting, deleting from the same database.

Comment: Please read the link I provided. It says:
"Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time. Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in time, however."
I would trust the authors of the database itself on this. I'm wondering how you are testing these simultaneous reads and writes?

Comment: He did not claim they are simultaneous :)